# Java Unchecked Cast from List containing wildcard to List of a specific type

Tags: java, generics, warnings, wildcard, unchecked-cast

I have the following classes

```java
public class PathPart {
    private final String pathPart;

    public PathPart(String pathPart) {
        this.pathPart = pathPart;
    }

    public String getPathPart() {
        return pathPart;
    }
}

public class Path {
    private final List<? extends PathPart> pathParts;

    public Path(String path) {
        this.pathParts = getPathParts(path);
    }

    public List<? extends PathPart> getPathParts() {
        return this.pathParts;
    }

    protected List<? extends PathPart> getPathParts(String path) {
        return Arrays.stream(path.split("/")).map(PathPart::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

public class FooBarPathPart extends PathPart {
    public FooBarPathPart(String pathPart) {
        super(isFoo(pathPart) ? "bar" : pathPart);
    }

    private static boolean isFoo(String pathPart) {
        return "foo".equals(pathPart);
    }
}


public class FooBarPath extends Path {
    public FooBarPath(String path) {
        super(path);
    }

    @Override
    public List<FooBarPathPart> getPathParts() {
        // UNCHECKED CAST HERE
        return (List<FooBarPathPart>) super.getPathParts();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<FooBarPathPart> getPathParts(String path) {
        return Arrays.stream(path.split("/")).map(FooBarPathPart::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

where I'd like to capture the structure of a filesystem path `/my/path/to/a/directory` in my `Path` object, which stores `my`, `path`, `to`, `a`, `directory` each as a `PathPart` object.

Now, I have a subclass of `PathPart` called `FooBarPathPart`, where if the path part is equal to `foo`, then I want it to change it to `bar`. And, I also have `FooBarPath` which is a subclass of `Path`, which stores a list of `FooBarPathPart`. So `/my/path/to/foo/directory` will essentially become `/my/path/to/bar/directory`

My issue is that I get an `Unchecked cast` warning from `List<? extends PathPart>` to `List<FooBarPath>` in my `getPathParts()` method in the `FooBarPath` class.

Is there a way to get rid of this unchecked cast warning properly? Is my usage of the wildcard correct here? Or is there a better way to approach this problem that doesn't involve the wildcard? I'm not very familiar with generics

Comment: I'd do it like this: `class Path<T extends PathPart> {  private final List<T> pathParts; ... }` and `class FooBarPath extends Path<FooBarPathPath>{ ... }`. If `Path` is not generic you can't do it without any casts as `pathParts` would not have any information other than that the list contains `PathPart` elements (or _any_ subclass).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, but I'm having trouble trying to create the list `return Arrays.stream(path.split("/")).map(PathPart::new).collect(Collectors.toList());` I'd like my `Path` object to be created by `new Path("/some/path")` and let the method inside actually create the list of `PathPart` objects. Is that possible?

Comment: There are some ways using reflection but I'd probably either go for an abstract common implementation and then `Path` and `FooBarPath` being siblings or, alternatively, provide the creator function to the constructor, e.g. via a factory method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637853/thomas)

I have solved the problem using generics and using a creator function. Here's the full solution:

```java
public class PathPart {
    private final String pathPart;

    public PathPart(String pathPart) {
        this.pathPart = pathPart;
    }

    public String getPathPart() {
        return pathPart;
    }
}

public class FooBarPathPart extends PathPart {
    public FooBarPathPart(String pathPart) {
        super(isFoo(pathPart) ? "bar" : pathPart);
    }

    private static boolean isFoo(String pathPart) {
        return "foo".equals(pathPart);
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractPath<T extends PathPart> {
    private final List<T> pathParts;
    private final Function<String, T> factory;

    public AbstractPath(Function<String, T> factory, String path) {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.pathParts = createPathParts(path);
    }

    public List<T> createPathParts() {
        return this.pathParts;
    }

    private List<T> createPathParts(String path) {
        return Arrays.stream(path.split("/")).map(factory).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

public class Path extends AbstractPath<PathPart> {
    public Path(String path) {
        super(PathPart::new, path);
    }
}

public class FooBarPath extends AbstractPath<FooBarPathPart> {
    public FooBarPath(String path) {
        super(FooBarPathPart::new, path);
    }
}
```